# What kind of behavior for an IoT device process

Tags: erlang

I have an Erlang server were a number of IoT cameras connect to using TCP and register themselves with their serial number.

The same server also runs a web service(cowboy) that serves APIs.

I want to create an API that will fetch a photo from the IoT camera.

I was thinking having the IoT processes modeled as gen_server and register with a global name using the IoT serial number.

When a request is received from cowboy I would do a gen_server:call() and wait for the photo to get downloaded.

My problem is that if the device is not registered the gen_server:call() will crash the process. I would rather just return an error message instead of crashing so I was thinking about using try...catch.

Is there a better way to do it? Or a better way to model the IoT processes?

Comment: Are the cameras going to maintain their TCP connection constantly, or only check in every so often?

Comment: Constantly, but there can alway be failures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different issues to clear up before knowing which way you would want to model this.

I'll make a few broad-sweeping assumptions before going too much further.

- Any central service that keeps track of devices will also persist the data those devices produce (so data can be retrieved whether or not they are connected right then, and data retrieval can be asynch/historical).
- Most devices will try to maintain a persistent connection over TCP.
- TCP connections will fail.
- Devices will remember their identity over time (MAC, serial number, label, location, or something else unique).

With these assumptions in place we can get to work.

Model your devices as processes, one process per connection.

Have a separate process maintain a registry of those devices according to whatever their ID is over time (and you will need a way of not having this spoofed, as devices can be trickier than user connections to secure -- this will probably be your most annoying challenge if the devices cannot be assigned a public/private key pair).

The registry process maintains a queue of image requests. Whenever a camera connects its queue is issued if any requests are pending. Any time a request comes in and the registry indicates that a camera is online right then, issue the request immediately. Sometimes that is as easy as making a data structure like

```
[{CameraID :: mac(), Status :: pid() | [image_request()]}]
```

(I'm assuming you're familiar with the [typespec language Erlang implements](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html). If not, read up on it -- its really good to know!)

If you have a lot of cameras, it might be a map:

```
#{CameraID := PID | [Request]}
```

Or you could use tagged tuples to be really slick (and easier to decipher and debug):

```
#{CameraID := {pid, PID} | {requests, [Request]}}
```

When you do a lookup for a camera you will either retrieve a list or a PID. Which type you receive indicates to you whether or not the camera is currently connected -- so you dispatch messages to the PID if that is what you get, add requests to the image request list if you receive a list, and whenever a camera connects you dispatch its request list to it before proceeding. Your registry process will need to `monitor/2` your camera's connection handling processes. From the registry's perspective those connection handlers *are* the cameras. Whenever one terminates (whether the process crashes, the connection fails, data gets funky, whatever) your registry must know to switch the failed camera's registered data from being a `pid()` to being a list of requests.

Incoming images would get saved to disk and logged in a separate registry (or you can use the file system as its own registry if you don't need metadata beyond what the image format and systematic filenames + directory names can provide).

Cowboy would serve either based on whatever it finds in the data directory, or based on what it retrieves from an image registry (if you decide to create such a process).

In any case, the way you would "find" a camera to talk to would not be via a globally registered name, but rather by routing (and sequentializing) messages to your cameras via a registry process that maintains knowledge of the cameras.

If you need persistent data then you'll want to persist the camera IDs to disk, but if not then just have a way for them to self-register and authenticate them in some way.

**Also consider**

You may not need to maintain the data over time, and you may never want to queue requests for a currently disconnected camera. It could be a "live only" system. In that case the task is even easier -- the registry is *only a message router*. I would probably *still want to save image data to disk* simply because you can get weird congestion otherwise. Deleting images after they have been retrieved/viewed is not unusual in this case.

This way you can issue asynchronous image requests and also build in a max-images-per-minute (or whatever interval) sort of rule where any request to a camera that has taken an image in the last X seconds (or minutes, whatever) will be served the currently cached image instead of going to the trouble to take a new one. This can immensely improve performance depending on the situation.

In any case, allowing the request to be a `cast` instead of a `call` allows you to break the strong link (potential to crash on a timeout) between the web service and the cameras. If an image doesn't exist yet, the web interface just can't see it. If it is pending, say so and provide a timeout -- but leave that stuff on the web interface side, along with showing only currently connected cameras.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer! One question: why is a registry process preferred to associating each camera process with a global name?

Comment: @ErlangWannabe A global name is only a name. A registry process can be tailored to know more meta and you can pick exactly how you are going to interact with it. You can wrap your calls the way I showed in a previous Q/A and `cast` to a PID (which is safe, whereas `cast` to a nonexistant name will crash outright -- a cast to a dead PID will just go into space, but not affect the caller), but for your application you will almost certainly want to know more stuff about the camera, like location, connect duration, etc. and log and display that stuff to the user. You would need a registry anyway!

Comment: @ErlangWannabe If you want to discuss this a bit the Erlang/OTP chatroom is easier: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75358/erlang-otp

Comment: I see, thanks! I was not trying to say that a global name is better, I just wanted to know why the registry process was preferred over it. Thanks a lot again. I have joined the channel!